# Flex saving progress bar

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, progress-bar

I am developing a static flex application which does not have a database connection, all the values are hardcoded(its just a prototype for the original app). Now when i click the save button, i need to get a message like saving in progress... please wait, I need to display this message for 3 seconds.

Please let me know how could this be done.

Thanks!

Cheers,

Deena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist create a timer with:

```
private var t:Timer = new Timer(3000,1);
```

Then add an event lister to resond when the timer will be finished:

```
t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, removeMSG);
//start timer
t.start();
```

Add, removeMSG function that will remove your progress bar or notifier:

```
private function removeMSG(e:TimerEvent):void{
    //code to remove the notification
}
```

Also if you plan to use ProgressBar control in Flex use `indeterminate="true"` that will make progress bar move without any feedback data from your webservice

Comment: No problem, that is why g33ks are here for :)

Answer (score 1):

I am putting in the complete code of how i did it for easy reference to other users.

First Create a savingProgressBar.mxml file with the progress bar with the required format.

Then in the parent page where you want the progress bar enter the following scrip code
[In my parent page i click a button called save and on click of it i am calling the save() function]

---

```
              private var pBar:IFlexDisplayObject;

    private function save()
    {
        pBar=PopUpManager.createPopUp( this, savingProgressBar, true);
        PopUpManager.centerPopUp(pBar);

             var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1500,1)
             myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
             myTimer.start();
        }

        public function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void 
        {
       PopUpManager.removePopUp(pBar);
        }   
      ]]>
```

Hope this helps,

cheers,

Deena

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer that triggers every 200ms or something, and each time it triggers have it add 3s/200ms to the progress bar.